# MySQL Workbench doesn't start

Tags: 14.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL Workbench from Ubuntu software center and it just doesn't start when I click on it. There's no error shown up. What's the matter?

UPDATE:

```
$ mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3 --verbose
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgnome-keyring.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ locate libgnome-keyring.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0

~$ locate libgnome-keyring.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Comment: Try running from the command line and see what errors, if any, are generated.

Comment: what's its name to run it from the terminal?

Comment: mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3 --verbose

Comment: @sohel4r, I updated the question.

Comment: locate libgnome-keyring.so also update this result

Comment: @sohel4r, updated.

Comment: Check thee following question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690359/mysql-workbench-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10 You will find the answer there!

Answer (score 1):

Create a symbolic link

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0

Comment: `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgnome-keyring.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`