# mysql workbench broken after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, mysql-workbench

`mysql-workbench` crashes soon after launch with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs
```

It happens since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10.

```
mysql-workbench:amd64/wily 6.3.4+dfsg-1build3 uptodate
mysql-workbench:i386 not installed
```

Output of `ldd /usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench-bin`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdc8937000)
    libmforms.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf77c7000)
    liblinux_utilities.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf7467000)
    libsqlide.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libsqlide.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf70fb000)
    libwbprivate.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf5756000)
    libwbpublic.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbpublic.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf4250000)
    libwbbase.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbbase.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf3fb5000)
    libgrt.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libgrt.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf3af4000)
    libcdbc.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libcdbc.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf388b000)
    libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2cf3602000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf2fb6000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf2d01000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f2cf29ee000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf27ea000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf2597000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf2288000)
    libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f2cf1c65000)
    libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f2cf1a18000)
    libatkmm-1.6.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1 (0x00007f2cf17d1000)
    libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f2cf155b000)
    libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cf1355000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f2cf0ddb000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f2cf0aa1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2cf071f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2cf0417000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2cf0200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2cefe36000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cefbe8000)
    libpangomm-1.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1 (0x00007f2cef9bd000)
    libcairomm-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 (0x00007f2cef79a000)
    libgnome-keyring.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 (0x00007f2cef574000)
    libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 (0x00007f2cef35e000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2cef13c000)
    libmdcanvas.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvas.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2ceec66000)
    libzip.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.2 (0x00007f2ceea55000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f2cee7e8000)
    libpcrecpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0x00007f2cee5de000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f2cee226000)
    libvsqlitepp.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvsqlitepp.so.3 (0x00007f2cee002000)
    libwbscintilla.so => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbscintilla.so (0x00007f2cedb98000)
    libmysqlparser.so.6.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libmysqlparser.so.6.2.3 (0x00007f2ceb14d000)
    libctemplate.so.2 => /usr/lib/libctemplate.so.2 (0x00007f2ceaeed000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f2ceac55000)
    libgdal.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1 (0x00007f2ce9e27000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f2ce9c22000)
    libmysqlcppconn.so.7 => /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7 (0x00007f2ce9905000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f2ce96f8000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f2ce94f2000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f2ce92cd000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2ce8f4c000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f2ce8d36000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f2ce8af8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2ce88da000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f2ce86d0000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f2ce84cd000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f2ce82bd000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f2ce80b2000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f2ce7ea8000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f2ce7ca5000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f2ce7aa2000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f2ce7890000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f2ce75e3000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f2ce733d000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f2ce7117000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f2ce6f13000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f2ce6d09000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f2ce6ae8000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2ce68ce000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2ce66c6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2ce64c2000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f2ce62ba000)
    libgiomm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f2ce5f21000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2ce5d1e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2cf8160000)
    libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f2ce5b15000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f2ce58c9000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f2ce55e7000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f2ce5253000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f2ce4f86000)
    libantlr3c_wb.so => /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/libantlr3c_wb.so (0x00007f2ce4d69000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f2ce4b40000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f2ce4912000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f2ce4710000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f2ce44f7000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f2ce42f2000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f2ce40ef000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f2ce3eec000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f2ce3ce5000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f2ce3ae2000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f2ce38dc000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f2ce36cd000)
    libarmadillo.so.5 => /usr/lib/libarmadillo.so.5 (0x00007f2ce34c6000)
    libproj.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.9 (0x00007f2ce326c000)
    libpoppler.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52 (0x00007f2ce2df3000)
    libfreexl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreexl.so.1 (0x00007f2ce2bea000)
    libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007f2ce29bc000)
    libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x00007f2ce275f000)
    libepsilon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepsilon.so.1 (0x00007f2ce2546000)
    libodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007f2ce22df000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f2ce20cd000)
    libkmlbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmlbase.so.1 (0x00007f2ce1eb3000)
    libkmldom.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmldom.so.1 (0x00007f2ce1bfb000)
    libkmlengine.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmlengine.so.1 (0x00007f2ce19c2000)
    libxerces-c-3.1.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxerces-c-3.1.so (0x00007f2ce1421000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007f2ce11e9000)
    libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007f2ce0f92000)
    libnetcdf.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so.7 (0x00007f2cddc43000)
    libhdf5_serial.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.10 (0x00007f2cdd78d000)
    libmfhdfalt.so.0 => /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0 (0x00007f2cdd568000)
    libdfalt.so.0 => /usr/lib/libdfalt.so.0 (0x00007f2cdd2c2000)
    libogdi.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/libogdi.so.3.2 (0x00007f2cdd0a1000)
    libgif.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so.4 (0x00007f2cdce98000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f2cdcc43000)
    libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f2cdca14000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f2cdc7f2000)
    libdapclient.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdapclient.so.6 (0x00007f2cdc574000)
    libdap.so.17 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdap.so.17 (0x00007f2cdc13d000)
    libspatialite.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7 (0x00007f2cdb9ac000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007f2cdb740000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f2cdb180000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f2cdaf5c000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2cdad40000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f2cdaae2000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f2cda8de000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f2cda6d8000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f2cda4d1000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f2cf82aa000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f2cda2be000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f2cd8807000)
    libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f2cd8587000)
    liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007f2cd7dd9000)
    libarpack.so.2 => /usr/lib/libarpack.so.2 (0x00007f2cd7b8b000)
    libsuperlu.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuperlu.so.4 (0x00007f2cd791f000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f2cd76c8000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f2cd7454000)
    libgeos-3.5.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.5.0.so (0x00007f2cd70ba000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f2cd6eb0000)
    libminizip.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminizip.so.1 (0x00007f2cd6ca4000)
    liburiparser.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburiparser.so.1 (0x00007f2cd6a8e000)
    libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 (0x00007f2cd686d000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f2cd6604000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f2cd61bb000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f2cd5f71000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f2cd5d1f000)
    liblwgeom-2.1.8.so => /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.1.8.so (0x00007f2cd5ac1000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f2cd588e000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f2cd5671000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f2cd543b000)
    libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28 (0x00007f2cd511f000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f2cd4f10000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f2cd4cf4000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f2cd49c9000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f2cd47bb000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f2cd44e8000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f2cd42b7000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f2cd40b3000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f2cd3ea8000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f2cd3c8d000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f2cd3a4d000)
    libjson-c.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f2cd3842000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f2cd360f000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f2cd338f000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f2cd312a000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f2cd2f17000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f2cd2cd8000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f2cd2ad4000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f2cd28cb000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f2cd2641000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f2cd239e000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f2cd216b000)
    libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f2cd1f56000)
    libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f2cd1d2d000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f2cd1b1e000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f2cd18d3000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f2cd169b000)
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove and install mysql-workbench after upgrading Ubuntu? I had no trouble when upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: yes, with no luck

Comment: `ldd /usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench-bin` run this command and past the output you can check missing library so that locate the missing library

Comment: here you are...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed version isn't the version of the Ubuntu Universe repository. Remove your installed version in `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench*
```

and in `/usr/local/lib`

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench
```

and install

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score -2):

In future please consider using MySQL Workbench apt repository provided by our team: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: Great, and where are the Wily repos? If you are already doing advertising, then please with matching repositories. 
For newcomers, it's hard to decide what repository is the right if there is no suitable. ;)

Comment: Ah right, my fault - I was thinking about 15.04. Repo for Wily will be avaiable later.